# Is there a simple way to organize fonts into folders and switch between them?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts

As a graphic designer, I have a large number of fonts installed on my PC (WIN XP SP3).  I need the variety, but the many fonts slow my applications considerably.  Is there a simple way to organize fonts into multiple folders and switch between them, preferably from within applications?  The only way I know to swap font files is to organize the fonts into folders, and rename the folders to "Fonts" as I need each one.  That would be terribly cumbersome.

Comment: How much memory do you have?  The more memory you have the better performance you will get.  If have XP SP3 which means you have a 32 bit OS and are stuck with a max of 4gb of RAM.  If you truly have a lot of fonts you need to upgrade to a 64 bit OS like Windows 7 or Windows 10 and give it 16gb and you won't have to organize your fonts into folders.

Comment: If you have 1+GB of fonts you want an SSD also.

Comment: I've used fonts and created my own fonts. A couple things come to mind, but I want to ask first: What program are you using (could be a factor)? Where are your fonts currently (relative to your PC's path)?

Comment: If you upgrade to windows 7 then you can use the `Font Cache Service` to improve the performance.

Comment: @cybernard I'm sorry I'm just now responding to your reply. I just got the email notification a cpl hours ago. The main PC I use for printing has a 2.53GHz Celeron w/ 960MB RAM. The hard drive shows 35.9GB free of 76.6GB total. I have 618 files in my WINDOWS/FONTS folder. As you say, a 64-bit system would solve the font clutter, but I can't use anything newer than XP b/c the main print prog I use (Microsoft PictureIt Publishing 2001) supports nothing newer.  For my purposes, no other prog works as well. IMHO Microsoft doesn't seem to know when they've actually got something right.

Comment: @cybernard Both of my laptops run Windows 7. I spent $$$ to upgrade one laptop to 7 Pro in order to use Microsoft's XP Emulator for Win7.  PIP2001 behaves very erratically, even w/ the emulator.  Hm.  Is there a 64-bit machine that runs XP (and a 64-bit version of the OS)?  Thank you for your answer.  I hadn't considered the memory factor, and it seems likely that just a memory upgrade will be a fix.

Comment: @ejbytes I'm sorry I'm just responding to your reply. I just got the email notice, a cpl hours ago. The main prog I use for printing is Microsoft PictureIt Publishing 2001. It's a dinosaur, but I've not found any other prog that suits my needs so well. I always place fonts directly into WINDOWS/FONTS to use from there, but I keep backups in other folders, as well. I've read something about a way to use fonts from various folders via a shortcut to speed up applications, but I'm not sure how to do that and can't find any specific info about how to go about it.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry I'm just now responding to your reply.  I was just notified a cpl hours ago.  I've considered an upgrade to Win7, and that's the OS on both my laptops, but the old program I use (Microsoft PictureIt Publishing 2001) won't run on anything newer than XP.  I've not found any other prog that suits my needs so well.  As I mentioned to cybernard, above, I've not been able to get the XP Emulator for 7Pro to run the prog correctly.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried “Windows Photo Gallery” and see if you could use that as an alternative? You can also try "Windows Live Photo Gallery” and you can download it from free from this site:   http://home.live.com/. You could try also try running your older programs in compatibility mode. Here’s an article that show you how to http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/bf416877-c83f-4476-a3da-8ec98dcf5f101033.mspx. You can also try "Digital Image 2006 Anniversary Edition" that the last version of "Microsoft Picture it" according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Picture_It.

Comment: I see now. I know how it is to use something and to be so in tune using it. I am also slow to change to the NEW technology just for the sake of technology. If it's not broke...I went from Win-95, then XP, skipped all the junk in between, and finally to Win-8.1, but downgraded to Win-7 and love it. Now I have a Surface Pro4 with Win10 and love it too. I digress. Usually I wouldn't ask what type of memory you have, but since your PC is old, it is necessary to find out. SIMM or DIMM? You need RAM memory! It's cheap and easy to self install. This will take care of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

RAM memory!

It's cheap and easy for self install. It's what's slowing your PC down. You have currently a super low amount of RAM for any standard today. And to help with old technology, you need to do some things manually; list below.

HOW TO INSTALL and what is RAM?:

- http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/identifying-and-upgrading-ram/

Since you have an old PC, it might be necessary to read the link, it explains the old question, "SIMM or DIMM"? Depending on the number of slots you have you could probably easily upgrade to 2GM or 4GB of RAM and it's really low cost.

Another problem with older technology too is how memory is managed and the settings and standards of "back then":

- Clear your CACHE and TEMP folders.

  - http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/have-windows-xp-how-do-you-empty-cache-thanks-9660/
- DEFRAG on your PC (a defrag routine reorganizes non-contiguous data files and tries to put them in a a more contiguous order, which speeds up "seek" and "search" time.

  - https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/snap_defrag.mspx?mfr=true
  - https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/disk_cleanup_overview.mspx?mfr=true
  - http://helpmerick.com/deep-cleaning-temporary-files-in-windows-xp.htm